# Install Glassfish 4 on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: server, amazon-ec2, glassfish

I have a EC2 instance on AWS running Ubuntu 13.10 and I need to install Glassfish 4 on it. I have found several tutorials on how to install Glassfish 3.x on it, including [this one](https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/how_to_run_glassfish_v3) and I tried to just do that tutorial substituting in glassfish 4 where appropriate, however, when I get to

```
/etc/init.d/glassfish start
```

I get a command not found error. What else do I need to do other than just substitute glassfish_v3/glassfishv3 with glassfish4?

Or, does anyone have a tutorial that is specific for glassfish4 on EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type as below

```
sudo service glassfish start
```

Alternative: If you like GUI ,

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

can help you to manage GUI way.

Comment: I have been working with jetty all year using this command and I didn't think of this at all... Thanks